# how to covert map values into string in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

i am able to print my Out-put in this format `System.out.println(map.get("email"));//this is printing fine` but i am unable to print same value after assigning it into a String variable. i tried: `String email=(String) map.get("email"); 
          System.out.println("Email--"+email);//But this is not printing`
How can i convert map values into string? Please help me.

My full code:

```
String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token="
              + authResponse.accessToken; 
            final StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer(); 
            final URL u = new URL(url);
            final URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
            final int end = 1000;
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            BufferedReader br = null; 
            isr = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            final int chk = 0; 
            String pat = "\"(.*)\": \"(.*)\",";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat);
            Matcher matcher = null;
            Map map = new HashMap();

            while ((url = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((chk >= 0) && ((chk < end))) {
                    matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
                    if(matcher.find()) {
                        map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
                    }
                    //r.append(url).append('\n');
                }
            }
              System.out.println(map.get("email")); 
              String email=(String) map.get("email"); 
              System.out.println(email);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`String email=map.get("email").toString();`

Answer (score 5):

Always use Generic type when using any collection or Map, unless of course you are using Java version older than `1.5`. So, declare your Map as : -

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And then you won't need a typecast at all. `map.get("email")` will give you `String` type result only.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the correct solution, not just fixing the code

Answer (score 1):

Use `toString()` or `""` with `+`,

`String s = map.get("email").toString();`

**Or**

`String s = map.get("email")+"";`

**-** And always prefer using `Generics` with `Collection`, so **you enter specific type into the collection and get that specific type out of the collection**.

**Eg:**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: If you want it to work with nulls, then use `""+`, or `String.valueOf(map.get("email"))` (it will give the string "null" in both cases)

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Only `map.get("email").toString()` won't work with nulls

Answer (score 0):

http://java.dzone.com/articles/two-ways-convert-java-map. Have a look at this link.Also Converting map values to string array [convert Map Values into String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328727/convert-map-values-into-string-array).

Answer (score 0):

It has been recommended to use type specific Map if you are working on java 1.5+. Your Map deceleration would be `Map<String,String> map`.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>(); // Diamond operator available in java 7 
String email= map.get("email");


Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(); // for java 5+ 
String email= map.get("email");
```