# How to convert hasmap values to array

Tags: java

I have a hashmap setup like this:

```
cars = new HashMap<Integer, Car>();
```

I now want to create an array of cars from the values:

```
Car[] carArray = (Car[])cars.values().toArray();
```

But it says I cannot cast

```
java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Car
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You could follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328727/convert-map-values-into-string-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are low-level constructs you shouldn't use unless their component type is primitive or you really know what you are doing (e.g. you have a performance need, and you are fully aware of how hard it can be to determine if you truly do have a performance need).

> I now want to create an array of cars from the values

No you don't. You want a `List<Car>` or `Collection<Car>`:

```
Collection<Car> justCars = cars.values();
// or, if you need list-specific stuff:
List<Car> justCars = new ArrayList<Car>(cars.values());
```

There's rather little arrays can do that lists cannot, but there's a lot that lists can do that arrays cannot.

But if you're somehow convinced you *must* have an array, this has nothing to do with lists; to convert a collection to an array, don't call `toArray()`. Instead:

```
anyCollection.toArray(new Car[0]); // always 0
anyCollection.toArray(Car[]::new); // or this
```

i.e. `cars.values().toArray(new Car[0])` does the job.

Comment: Ah i was using array because it had a sort() method, when i used ArrayList i couldn't simply do `.sort()` and have it call my compareTo method which i had implemented with `Comparable` interface. But i'll go back to array list and figure out how to use the sort method.

Comment: arrays do not have a sort method. There's `Arrays.sort()`. If you want to sort a list on its natural order, `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())` is roughly equivalent to `Arrays.sort(arr);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to construct an array of the correct type. `toArray()` without any arguments always returns an array of `Object`s.

```java
Car[] carArray = cars.values().toArray(Car[]::new);
```